# Looking a way to know if a youtube video exit?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to validate if an youtube video exist (is valide) ? In my site, a user can post a video youtube by putting his link, i'm getting the id and need to check if the video is working before saving it.

Here is the code i used before but now i have a 429 Too Many Requests

```
$file_headers = @get_headers('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='. $id_video.'&feature=youtu.be');
if ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK') {
    $this->idvideo = $id_video;
} else {
    $context->addViolationAt('lien', 'error_mess', array(), null);
}
```

PS: I was asking mysel why before i had not the 429 error ? I was on a mutual server and now i use a vps. I that beacause before i didn't have my own ip ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [videos.list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with id of the video to see if it will return a result.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim and thank you for your answer. It was that! I have just one problem now, if i want to put a referer (the ip of my vps server or the name of my website) it doesn't work, it says : "code": 403, "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed." So i use the api with my public key without referer for the moment... Any idea about what happened ? (sorry for my english...)